# Jquery - Chain functions with deferred and promises but without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I need to execute 2 functions one after the other with the stuff in function "A" fully completing before the stuff in function "B" executes...

I can't find an example that is not using setTimeout .. which is strange ...

I have the  following example below ( [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012556/make-synchronous-function-in-javascript) ) , is it supposed to work ?? How could I test if it is working ? What dummy code could I use to simulate the part "//do stuff with SharePoint JSOM" taking 5 secs to 30 secs ,say .

```
var a = function() {
var defer = $.Deferred();

//do stuff with SharePoint JSOM

console.log('a() called');

return defer;
};

var b = function() {
var defer = $.Deferred();

console.log('b() called');


return defer;
};



a().then(b);
```

Comment: Yes, just use `setTimeout` as a dummy.

Comment: If `b` doesn't do anything asynchronous, it should not return a deferred (or promise). `then` also works with synchronous callbacks.

Comment: according to what I tested and read you can't use setTimeout as a dummy since it simply does not halt the calling code. And I can't use preset delays.

Comment: Yes, deferreds or JSOM don't halt the calling code either, that's their whole point.

Comment: HI I don't mean halt the code completely. Just halt the execution of function B until function A executes, ( without using setTimeout ), Are you saying this is not the intended purpose of  Jquery deferred/promises ?

Comment: `b` is not halted - it doesn't execute yet. It's deferred, scheduled to be executed after `a` finishes. *That's* what deferred objects do. So yes, just use  `setTimeout` to asynchronously resolve the promise that `a` returns.

Answer (score 4):

Simple use a `promise` (*vanilla JS*) and chain them with `then`.

```js
function a() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        console.log("wait two seconds ...");

        // this timeout is only here for demo purpose ;)
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("A");
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function b() {
    console.log("B");
}

a().then(b);
```

If you want to use jQuery `deffered` its nearly the same.

```js
function a() {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    
    console.log("wait two seconds ...");

    // this timeout is only here for demo purpose ;)
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("A");
        defer.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    
    return defer;
}

function b() {
    console.log("B");
}

a().then(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I am aware of this way, But was just wondering to get a working example using jquery promises...

Comment: But doesn't setTimeout fix a set timeout of 2000 ms ? I don't want a fixed timeout. I want B to execute whenever A finishes naturally.

Comment: `setTimeout` is only for example there. You can completly remove it. ;) See here: https://jsfiddle.net/cxcrk8vr/ @Zertix.net

Comment: OK , so you are saying with  defer.resolve(); outside the setTimeout statement, it would still wait for all stuff ( functions,etc) to complete as long as  defer.resolve();  is the last line ?. I couldn't test it since I haven't got some dummy function that runs for seconds on its own..

Comment: Correct. Calling `defer.resolve();` says `ok, I'm done, next one please`. ;) For example, you could call `defer.resolve();` in a ajax callback. So the execution of `b()` would wait until the ajax request is complete. @Zertix.net

Comment: @Zertix.net well, no, because you would still want to execute .resolve() only after whatever action you are performing completes, which will require some kind of callback (just like setTimeout does). promises don't avoid the need for callbacks.

Comment: I think he asks because he want to know if `setTimeout` is **needed** for `deffered` or `promise`. And it is not. He can call `resolve` whenever the action of `a()` is finished. If in an `setTimeout`, `ajax` or anything else.