# jQuery/JavaScript read a local text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

For some reason I got stuck with this 'thing'

As you can see I want to try to read the count.txt. This is working perfectly but for some reason the

```
alert(code);
```

is coming up **after** the

```
alert("The number can't be smaler then 0");
```

For me it makes no sense because I'd call the alert(count) **before** the alert("The number...")
Any ideas why the jQuery  function (alert) is called after the other alert?

```
function leftFunction() {
    jQuery.get('count.txt', function(data) {
        var count = data;
        alert(count);
    });
    scrolling = true;
    if(number == 0) {
        alert("The number can't be smaler then 0");
        return;
    }
    number--;
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "latest" + number + ".jpg";
}
```

Comment: That's related to being sync/async. Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012556/make-synchronous-function-in-javascript

Comment: [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) callback function is asynchronous _"If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately."_

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Red fx says in the comments, it's related to JavaScript being asynchronous. Try something like this instead:

```
function leftFunction() {
    jQuery.get('count.txt', function(data) {
        var count = data;
        alert(count);
    }).done(function() {
        scrolling = true;
        if (number == 0) {
            alert("The number can't be smaler then 0");
            return;
        }
    });
    number--;
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "latest" + number + ".jpg";
}
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Thanks alot for the snippet :)